# R - Manipulate string based on pattern

Tags: regex, r, string

This is the name of a file that I have on R:

```
> lst.files[1]
[1] "clt_Amon_CanESM2_rcp45_185001-230012.nc"
```

What I need to do is capture just the part until the 4th underscore (including), so it would be something like this:

```
clt_Amon_CanESM2_rcp45_
```

How can I get this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you always have (at least) four underscores, then you could do something like this:

```
regmatches(lst, regexec(".*_.*_.*_.*_", lst.files[1]))[[1]]
# [1] "clt_Amon_CanESM2_rcp45_"
```

If potentially not always four, but no underscores in the second part, you could do something like this:

```
regmatches(lst, regexec(".*_", lst.files[1]))[[1]]
# [1] "clt_Amon_CanESM2_rcp45_"
```

This doesn't require any extra package, just base R.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `qdap` package, you can do the following.

```
x <- "clt_Amon_CanESM2_rcp45_185001-230012.nc"

library(qdap)
beg2char(x, "_", 4, include = TRUE)
# [1] "clt_Amon_CanESM2_rcp45_"
```

Comment: Great answer but I would prefer to stick to R's native commands. I am loading too many packages already and eventually I will get conflict between some commands :D

Comment: THe function is new for me. +1

Comment: @akrun I am glad that you found this useful. :)

Comment: @jazzurro I noted down this in my book to use it next time :-)

Comment: Wow, you completed >7000 review tasks, impressive!

Comment: @akrun I've been helping reviews for trio a lot these days. That's my support for SO. I have not been able to commit myself to answer questions as I used to be able to. I somewhat got a bit of time this month, so I try to catch up with you guys. Hope to see you in the chat room some time. I hope you have been doing well.

Comment: Yes, i will be in the chat room later in the evening.  See you later.

Comment: @akrun OK. I may be able to drop by tonight. See ya.

Answer (score 2):

We can also capture the repeating patterns as a group using `sub`.  We match one more more characters from the beginning (`^`) of the string that is not an underscore (`[^_]+`) followed by an underscore (`\\_`) which is repeated 4 times (`{4}`), capture that as a group by wrapping with parentheses followed by zero or more characters (`.*`).  We replace it with the capture group (`\\1`) to get the expected output.

```
sub('^(([^_]+\\_){4}).*', '\\1', str1)
#[1] "clt_Amon_CanESM2_rcp45_"
```

#### data

```
str1 <-  "clt_Amon_CanESM2_rcp45_185001-230012.nc"
```